# WPF/XAML - DataTriggers to set ValidatesOnDataErrors = false/true when a radio button is checked

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, triggers

I am working on an application that implements the MVVM design pattern with DataAnnotations. The application is a dynamically generated list of pages. On one of those pages, I have 10 required fields with 2 yes/no radio buttons. Those 10 fields are divided into two groups and each group is wwapped with a border tag. Each border's visibility is bound with the radio buttons for hidden/visible.

My question is if yes was selected and the related 5 required text boxes are displayed how can i set the ValidatesOnDataErrors to false/true and clear the text boxes values of the other hidden required TextBoxes?

Here is a code Snippet.

thanks

```
<Border>
<Border.Style>
  <Style>
   <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=PresentlyEmployed_yes, Path=IsChecked}"
                  Value="True">
       <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
     </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
  </Border.Style>
  <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
   <Label Name="JobTitle"
               Content="{x:Static properties:Resources.JobTitlelbl}" />
    <TextBox Name="JobTitle" Text="{Binding JobTitle, Mode=TwoWay, 
     ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
     <TextBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
       <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding PrimaryInsuredBusinessDuties, Mode=TwoWay,
          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True}" />
       <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=PresentlyEmployed_yes, Path=IsChecked}"
          Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding JobTitle, Mode=TwoWay, 
           ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
       </DataTrigger>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=PresentlyEmployed_yes, Path=IsChecked}"
         Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding JobTitle, Mode=TwoWay, 
          ValidatesOnDataErrors=False, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
       </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
   </TextBox>
  </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Why don't you just rebind the `Text` values without the `ValidatesOnDataErrors` in your Trigger?

Comment: I tried that and it didnt work. The problem is that once the ValidatesOnDataErrors is set to True and i try to rebind it with 
ValidatesOnDataErrors = False or with out the ValidatesOnDataErrors or even if i dont bind it to anything, it dosnt not remove the validation. Here is how my property looks like: 

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field!")]
public string JobTitle
{
 get
 {
   return _jobTitle;
 }
 set
 {
   _jobTitle = value;
 }
}

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps it is not updating the UI because the BindingSource isn't changing. Try raising the `PropertyChanged` event in your ViewModel when the `RadioButton` changes, in addition to rebinding the property.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Let me try that, will get back in few moments.

Comment: Still no luck! It turns the valudation on but not off. BTW, in my radiobutton property setter i was raising the onpropertychanged event and pass the property name. I do that in every property setter. Am i missing somthing here?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `Validation.Template` to `{x:Null}` if it shouldn't show the Validation Error

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ListBoxItem>Validate Value 1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Validate Value 2</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value1, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=MyListBox}" Value="1" >
                        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value2, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=MyListBox}" Value="0" >
                        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: That would not show the error on the UI, however, the page is still not valid which means i still can not fire the nextCommand because of the required field validation for the JobTitle property.

Comment: Can't you alter your `IsValid` code to only check validation on specific properties based on which `RadioButton` is checked?

Comment: That's how i currently have it. In my ValidationViewModelBase class i am inheriting the IDataErrorInfo and IValidationExceptionHandler. i am filtering the validationAttribute list in the "this" method by adding or removing field validation based on the passed property name. However, this application has over 500 fields so the validation base class looks ugly at the moment.

Comment: @Bobby I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you post a simplified bit of code showing your `IDataError` implementation?

Comment: I posted my code below, please take a look and let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sure, here is how my validationbase class looks like (Simplified)

    public class ValidationViewModelBase : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo,   IValidationExceptionHandler
    {
    private Dictionary<string, Func<ValidationViewModelBase, object>> _propertyGetters;
    private Dictionary<string, ValidationAttribute[]> _validators;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the error message for the property with the given name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property</param>
    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
         IList<string> fieldsNames = new List<string>();
    {
    if (propertyName == "PresentlyEmployed")
      {
        //if its true then
        fieldsNames.Add("JobTitle");

        AddFieldsValidation(fieldsNames); 
        }else{

        fieldsNames.Add("EmploymentAddress");

        RemoveValidation(fieldsNames); 
    }

  if (this.propertyGetters.ContainsKey(propertyName))
      {
            var propertyValue = this.propertyGetters[propertyName](this);
        var errorMessages = this.validators[propertyName]
                        .Where(v => !v.IsValid(propertyValue))
                        .Select(v => v.ErrorMessage).ToArray();
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errorMessages);
      }
    return string.Empty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an error message indicating what is wrong with this object.
    /// </summary>
    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
        var errors = from validator in this.validators
                        from attribute in validator.Value
            where !attribute.IsValid(this.propertyGetters[validator.Key](this))
            select attribute.ErrorMessage;

            return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors.ToArray());
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of properties which have a validation attribute and are  currently valid
    /// </summary>
    public int ValidPropertiesCount
    {
        get
        {
            var query = from validator in this.validators
                where validator.Value.All(attribute => attribute.IsValid(this.propertyGetters[validator.Key](this)))
                select validator;

            var count = query.Count() - this.validationExceptionCount;
            return count;
            }
        }
}

/// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of properties which have a validation attribute
    /// </summary>
    public int TotalPropertiesWithValidationCount
    {
        get
        {
            return this.validators.Count();
        }
    }

public ValidationViewModelBase()
    {
        this.validators = this.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => this.GetValidations(p).Length != 0)
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => this.GetValidations(p));

        this.propertyGetters = this.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => this.GetValidations(p).Length != 0)
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => this.GetValueGetter(p));
    }

private ValidationAttribute[] GetValidations(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return (ValidationAttribute[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true);
    }

    private Func<ValidationViewModelBase, object> GetValueGetter(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return new Func<ValidationViewModelBase, object>(viewmodel => property.GetValue(viewmodel, null));
    }

    private int validationExceptionCount;

    public void ValidationExceptionsChanged(int count)
    {
        this.validationExceptionCount = count;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ValidPropertiesCount");
    }
```

Comment: @Rachel: the above code is currently doing the job. However, i am not so proud of the way i am adding or removing fields. So i thought maybe DataTriggers can do the job for me. if you have different approach please let me know. 

thanks