# Disable validation on disabled TextBox

Tags: wpf

```
<Binding Path="AttachmentName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                          <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <valid:AttachmentNameValidationRule ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                          </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
```

Validator checks if entered value is in proper format: file.extension. Unfortunelly, textBox is red when control IsEnabled == false (because content is "").

Any idea how to disable validation? Tried some stuff with x:referense and passing UIElement to validator, but didnt work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling or disabling validation upon context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900569/enabling-or-disabling-validation-upon-context)

Answer (score 9):

The original credit goes to the [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/97100980-5ca1-4b46-a22a-88d025fe9bde/enabling-and-disabling-validation-based-on-isenabled-property?forum=wpf) in @ydoow's answer.

It is easily achieved with a trigger that sets the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` to null when the control is disabled.

The property is still validated but user is not notified about validation results.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```